# How style the element before specified one

Tags: css, css-selectors

We all know how the adjacent selector works (p+p), but I wonder if there's an option to style an element that appears just before the specified one? For example:

```
<p id="one"></p>
<p id="two"></p>
```

I would like to style the first element that appears just before the p#two. How to do this without JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS4 it will be possible to specify the element to which the style applies (not just the last the last element in a selector). [CSS Selector Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) So in the future this should work:

```
p! + p { /* your styles here */ }
```

However, as far as i know, no browser does support them right now.